# Writing R code to convert rotated netCDF file to regualar grid and dataframe

Tags: r

I am looking for R code to extract/convert data from netCDF file to dataframe or CSV file. But, the netCDF is a rotated file in longitude and latitude (rlon and rlat slot). I searched many codes from net tutorials, but I was not able to convert/extract the netCDF file to a dataframe, to enable me to subset the region of interest (lon-min=20 and lon-max=50; lat-min= -40 and lat-max= 8)  and simulate future projection with marine species distribution model in R.

Can anyone help me with the  R code for extracting the data from the neCDF to dataframe?

Attached is an example of a rotated netCDF file.

nc_file <- 'tos_Omon_GFDL-CM3_rcp85_r1i1p1_209601-210012.nc'
nc<-nc_open(nc_file)
print(nc)
double time_bnds[bnds,time]
long_name: time axis boundaries
units: days since 2006-01-01 00:00:00
float lat[rlon,rlat]
long_name: latitude coordinate
units: degrees_north
standard_name: latitude
bounds: lat_vertices
double lat_vertices[vertices,rlon,rlat]
units: degrees_north
float lon[rlon,rlat]
long_name: longitude coordinate
units: degrees_east
standard_name: longitude
bounds: lon_vertices
double lon_vertices[vertices,rlon,rlat]
units: degrees_east

```
 5 dimensions:
    time  Size:60   *** is unlimited ***
        long_name: time
        units: days since 2006-01-01 00:00:00
        cartesian_axis: T
        calendar_type: noleap
        calendar: noleap
        bounds: time_bnds
        standard_name: time
        axis: T
    bnds  Size:2
        long_name: vertex number
        cartesian_axis: N
    rlat  Size:200
        long_name: latitude in rotated pole grid
        units: degrees
        axis: Y
        standard_name: grid_latitude
    rlon  Size:360
        long_name: longitude in rotated pole grid
        units: degrees
        axis: X
        standard_name: grid_longitude
    vertices  Size:4
```